# Neo4j-shell not working on Mac Community edition 3.3.0

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-shell

I'm new to Neo4j and have installed the Community Edition (3.3.0).  I'm working through tutorials that reference neo4j-shell.  However, every time I try to run it I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/neo4j-shell: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run the Desktop version and use its terminal, but get the same thing.  I even installed it with Homebrew (have since uninstalled) and it seemed to respond but could not connect to anything even when I used the appropriate switches.  I've also tried things I've found searching here and within the Google Group to no avail.

Could anyone please let me know how to get this running with Community Edition, or if not possible, please let me know how to otherwise.  I'm running on a Mac and installed using the .dmg file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, cypher-shell is the command to use now.

It only seems to work for me with the Desktop edition.  I'm going to close this topic out and likely post the issue, unless I can find a solution, as a cypher-shell topic.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to install anything. Just download the linux distribution (.tar.gz)  , extract it , then use terminal to go into the new folder and start Neo4j.

You can start Neo4j in console mode by running `./bin/neo4j` in console

If you have any problems getting it to run try using the following command  :

`chmod +x ./bin/*.sh`

to make the scripts executable.

On another note - Neo4j Enterprise is free - you don’t have to use community edition!

I wrote a blog post about this subject.

https://blog.igovsol.com/2017/11/14/Neo4j-330-is-out-but-where-are-the-open-source-enterprise-binaries.html

Comment: I'll try this.  Thanks.  As far as your point on using Enterprise vs. Community, what's the difference?  Enterprise says it's a "free trial".  Why am I better off installing Enterprise?  Is there any benefit to the desktop edition that seems to be more self-contained?

Comment: The above doesn't work for me.  When I run `./bin/neo4j` I get `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"`.  When I run `chmod +x ./bin/*.sh` I get `chmod: ./bin/*.sh: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @grega - That is a good question. Confusing right?  Neo4j Enterprise is free under it’s open source AGPL license - but Neo4j Inc has made it hard to get the open source packaged binary from them.   You don’t need to install Neo4j Enterprise - just download the binary, extract and run ./bin/neo4j console from a terminal.   If you want free open source enterprise binaries - you can download from my company’s website.  We compile them from source for the Neo4j community members who don’t want to agree to commercial or ‘trial’ licenses.

Comment: Also, you really don’t need Neo4j desktop. In fact, I am suspicious that one of its intentions is getting you to agree to an unnecessary trial license of Neo4j Enterprise.  If you have no intention of buying a commercial enterprise package, then stick with the AGPL licensed binaries.  The blog post I posted explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

`neo4j-shell` is **deprecated since version `3.0`**, and you should use the `cypher-shell` instead.

You can still use `neo4j-shell` if you want, but you need to add the following key into `neo4.conf` file : `dbms.shell.enabled=true`.

All the Neo4j's console tools are located under the `NEO4J_HOME/bin` folder.

If you use the Desktop edition, as you have seen, there a tab to have a console, and you are directly under the `NEO4J_HOME`.

I'm not an expert on MacOS, but normally the `dmg` package should unpack Neo4j somewhere on your filesystem.

You can also use the `unix` version on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

You should be using cypher-shell with the new versions of Neo4j. (3.x +)  Make sure to update your ./conf/neo4j.conf file and look for dbms.shell.enabled which will be commented out by default.  Remove the # so it says dbms.shell.enabled=true